# 3130cn driver for ubuntu

Tags: printer, ubuntu-10.04

Ubuntu 10.04 does not come with a driver for 3130cn. Dell does not offer a driver for Ubuntu but for SUSE and RedHat

Answer (score 1):

Download the SuSE driver from Dell and open in Archive Manager. If you extract the ppd file from it, you can point Ubuntu to it when prompted.